# Download Request from AWS S3 in Swift

Tags: swift, amazon-s3

I am trying to download my files from AWS S3 onto my application, using Swift 2. 
I have added a create download request within the function.

```
 func checkS3Download(){
    // create download request
    let downloadFilePath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("item")
    let downloadingFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:downloadFilePath)
    let downloadRequest: AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest()
    downloadRequest.bucket = "bucketname"
    downloadRequest.key = "item"
    downloadRequest.downloadingFileURL = downloadingFileURL
```

I am having issues with the code below:
trying to get the server to download onto my application.

```
      let transferManager.download(downloadRequest).continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: {(task: AWSTask) -> AnyObject in

        if task.error {
            if (task.error.domain == AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain) {
                switch task.error.code {
                case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled, AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused:
                    break
                default:
                    NSLog("Error: %@", task.error)
                }
            }
            else {
                // Unknown error.
                NSLog("Error: %@", task.error)
            }
        }
        if task.result {
            var downloadOutput: AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadOutput = task.result
            //File downloaded successfully.
        }
        return nil
    })

}
```

If anyone can help me understand how to fix my issues in order to download on my app, i would be very appreciative.

Comment: What exact error message are you getting?

Comment: let transferManager.download(downloadRequest).continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: {(task: AWSTask) -> AnyObject in << this line gets: consecutive statements  on a line must be separated by ';' which is not swift. second being there type annotation missing in pattern and the third being: type of expression is ambiguous without context

Comment: i dont know if i am doing the Download Request correctly, do you happen to know how to do it effectively? @RodrigoM

Comment: Sorry looks like a Swift syntax issue; I am not sure what the correct syntax is. I was 'hoping' to see an AWS S3 error.

Comment: <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>DEB42BF56C4AABB6</RequestId><HostId>6mLYDtZ6FtCxiocmh+8DrpDc+Iqv4pKCBIy+R0uhEPfXwUjjkPlDG9Mf5kaddYuZklqzAlJQvXE=</HostId></Error>] << this is the error i receive when i try run the app. Is this a AWS S3 error? @rodrigoM

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting that message, the app code is probably working. That is an AWS error, related to S3 bucket permissions.

Make sure your S3 bucket has the correct permission. The correct bucket policy will look like this:

```
{
   "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1350703615347",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"],
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

The first block grants get (download) S3 permission to all objects within the bucket. The second block grants list permission on the bucket itself.

You should update the policy by checking the S3 bucket properties, under the Properties tab, then clicking on Edit bucket policy.

Comment: I have fixed the issues for access denied - its because i didn't have list bucket in my policy.

Comment: i have my access key and secret key and all information required, but i dont understand the download request to download the bucket to my iPhone.. does anyone?